# Filter by Day of Week in Flask-Admin

Tags: python, flask-admin

The DB Model is

```
class DoctorWaitTimes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'doctorwaittimes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    waittime = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Then in the ModelView Class

```
column_filters = ['datetime']
```

This allows the user to select

- equals
- not equals
- greater than
- smaller than
- between
- not between
- empty

and a clickable calendar is displayed for ease of entry of dates/times. This is perfect however there are two changes I would like to make.

I would like to remove the following options:

- not equals
- greater than
- smaller than
- not between
- empty

but I can't find anything in the docs. Secondly, I would like to be able to filter by day of the week. So for example it will only display every Tuesday.

```
column_filters = [
        FilterTerminal(
            DoctorWaitTimes.datetime, 'Day of Week', 
            options=(('1', 'Monday'), ('2', 'Tuesday'))
        ), 'datetime'
    ]
```

However, I am unsure how to get the actual filter to work. In MySQL you can run

```
SELECT * FROM doctorwaittimes WHERE AND DAYOFWEEK(datetime) = 1;
```

to select Mondays, but I am not sure how to do it using DB Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove several types of filters from your view use [FilterConverter](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/filters.py#L343) class. It has several lists of filters applicable to each type of column. Subclass it and replace these lists to remove undesired filters. Specify the new class as `filter_converter` attribute of your view:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView, filters

class DoctorFilterConverter(filters.FilterConverter):
    datetime_filters = (
        filters.DateTimeEqualFilter,
        filters.DateTimeBetweenFilter
    )

class DoctorView(ModelView):
    filter_converter = DoctorFilterConverter()
    column_filters = ['datetime']
```

You can use the same way to add new filters. Day-of-the-week filter can be implemented this way:

```
class DayOfWeekFilter(filters.BaseSQLAFilter):
    def __init__(self, column, name, options=None, data_type=None):
        options = (
            ('1', filters.lazy_gettext(u'Monday')),
            ('2', filters.lazy_gettext(u'Tuesday')),
            ('3', filters.lazy_gettext(u'Wednesday')),
            ('4', filters.lazy_gettext(u'Thursday')),
            ('5', filters.lazy_gettext(u'Friday')),
            ('6', filters.lazy_gettext(u'Saturday')),
            ('7', filters.lazy_gettext(u'Sunday'))
        )
        super(DayOfWeekFilter, self).__init__(column, name, options, data_type)

    def operation(self):
        return filters.lazy_gettext('day of week')

    def validate(self, value):
        return value in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')

    def apply(self, query, value, alias=None):
        return query.filter(db.func.extract('dow', self.get_column(alias)) == value)
```

Then you can add it to `datetime_filters`:

```
class DoctorFilterConverter(filters.FilterConverter):
    datetime_filters = (
        filters.DateTimeEqualFilter,
        filters.DateTimeBetweenFilter,
        DayOfWeekFilter
    )
```

Note that there is no universal SQL function to extract day of the week. I used PostgreSQL [EXTRACT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) function. In MySQL you can try to use [WEEKDAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function:

```
def apply(self, query, value, alias=None):
    return query.filter(db.func.weekday(self.get_column(alias)) == value)
```

And you'll need to change the numeration of options as WEEKDAY function returns 0 for Monday and 6 for Sunday.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the help!